# width transition - divs overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs positioned horizontally next to each other inside a container. I want each div to expand width on hover to the full width of the container.
The problem is that after the transition when the pointer is no longer hovering the left div (which is first in the html flow) is overlapped under the right div.

Here's an example. 
To recreate just place the pointer on the left div until the transition is finished, then take the pointer off the div.
The desired effect is that the width will decrease gradually (just like the right div).

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#wrap { position: relative; width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; }

#one, #two { height: 100px; position: absolute; transition: width 1s ease-out; }

#one { width: 300px; background: #49d7b0; }
#two { right: 0; width: 200px; background: #d8c800; }

#one:hover, #two:hover { width: 500px; z-index: 1; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="z-index.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrap">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a z-index problem. You must to increment the z-index depending on where the mouse is. I think in first impression this will be hard to achieve only with css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the z-index with more difference between the un-hovered and the hovered state (for instance, go from 1 to 10).

Add transition on the z-index also ... But only when going back to the default state.

This way, when you change the hover from one element to the other, the newly hovered element will have immediately the high z-index, while the un-hovered is slowly dreasing it. And the newly hovered element will be in front.

Demo: (with the key styles in first place)

```css
#one:hover,
#two:hover {
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: width 1s ease-out, z-index 0s linear;
}
#one,
#two {
  z-index: 1;
  transition: width 1s ease-out, z-index 1s linear;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#one,
#two {
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
#one {
  width: 300px;
  background: #49d7b0;
}
#two {
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #d8c800;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="z-index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

**[animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)** can do the trick here. Actually `z-index` cause the issue here. You can solve following way.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#wrap { position: relative; width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; }

#one, #two { height: 100px; position: absolute; transition: width 1s ease-out; }

#one { width: 300px; background: #49d7b0; animation: movedec 1s; }
#two { right: 0; width: 200px; background: #d8c800; }

#one:hover { animation: moveinc 1s forwards;  -webkit-animation: moveinc 1s forwards; }
#two:hover { width: 500px;  }

@keyframes moveinc {
    from {width: 300px; z-index: 1;}
    to {width: 500px; z-index: 1;}
}

@keyframes movedec {
    from {width: 500px; z-index: 1;}
    to {width: 300px; z-index: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveinc {
    from {width: 300px; z-index: 1;}
    to {width: 500px; z-index: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes movedec {
    from {width: 500px; z-index: 1;}
    to {width: 300px; z-index: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It would be better to remove one's handler while the other transition is triggered

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a problem, just the way overflows have to work. You have 2 options:

1) Use CSS keyframe animations - that way, you can give the hovered div a higher z-index, and have the reverse animation keep the z-index higher (dropping it back to a lower index at the very end of the animation).

2) use javascript/jquery (if you want this to work well on all devices/browsers, I would recommend Jquery anyway, which gives support to older browsers like IE8 that don't support css3)